# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException on MessageDialog WINUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog, winui

When I try to invoke an MessageDialog my app crashes with the following error message:

```
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid Window Identifier. (0x80070578)'
```

This occurs both on the App.xaml.xs and in an helper I have for that propose.

Code on app.xaml:

```
var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Excedeu o limite de tentativas para fazer login.");
var result = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Code on helper:

```
public static async Task ShowAsync(String keyName)
        {
            var msg = LocalizationHelper.GetValue(keyName);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg)) msg = keyName;

            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(msg);
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ContentDialog` class to build your dialog experience.

The `MessageDialog` API is deprecated as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

> Use the ContentDialog class to build your dialog experience. Don't use the deprecated MessageDialog API.

Answer (score 2):

In desktop apps on .NET 5 or later, you'll need to use the `InitializeWithWindow.Initialize` method on your `MessageDialog` object before popping the dialog.

This is because desktop apps can have more than one window object, so you'll need to specify the owner window for your dialog.

For example:

```cs
var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("example");
var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(myWindow);
WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(messageDialog, hwnd);
var result = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

For more [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/winrt-com-interop-csharp)